# numpy e^i(theta) and trigonometric cos(theta) + isin(theta) does not match

Tags: python, numpy, math

I read,

[image]

So I tried to do apply this to a list of points as shown below

[image]

And below part works perfectly as expected.

```
Zj = np.array([1. +0.j , 0.5+0.5j, 0. +0.j , 0.5-0.5j, 1. +0.j ])
δj      = Zj[1: ] - Zj[:-1]
assert(np.allclose(δj, np.array([-.5+0.5j , -.5-.5j, 0.5-.5j, .5+.5j])))
assert(np.allclose(np.angle(δj, deg=True) , np.array([ 135., -135.,  -45.,   45.])))
```

But when I take $e^{i\theta}$ that does not work as intended.

```
e_iVj   = -1j * ((δj)/abs(δj))
assert(np.allclose(np.cos(np.angle(δj)) + np.sin(np.angle(δj)), e_iVj))
```

EDIT:

As @hpaulg suggested, I've added 1j component in to sin. but still its not quite match up with ref to signs. Values are correct

```
>>> np.cos(np.angle(δj)) + 1j* np.sin(np.angle(δj))
array([-0.70710678+0.70710678j, -0.70710678-0.70710678j,
        0.70710678-0.70710678j,  0.70710678+0.70710678j])
>>> e_iVj
array([ 0.70710678+0.70710678j, -0.70710678+0.70710678j,
       -0.70710678-0.70710678j,  0.70710678-0.70710678j])
>>> 1j * ((δj)/abs(δj))
array([-0.70710678-0.70710678j,  0.70710678-0.70710678j,
        0.70710678+0.70710678j, -0.70710678+0.70710678j])
```

@peterwhy

Could you please let me know if the equation on the first snippet is correct as per your understanding.

```
-- Confirming Angles are represented correctly
>>> Zj= Zj[0]
>>> Zj_p1 = Zj_p1[0]
>>> δj = Zj_p1 - Zj
>>> np.angle(δj, deg=True)
135.0 # Confirmed ok
```

```
-- Showing e^iϑ = δj/abs(δj)
>>> ϑ = np.angle(δj)
>>> e_iϑ = np.exp(1j*ϑ)
>>> e_iϑ
(-0.7071067811865475+0.7071067811865476j)

>>> δj/abs(δj)
(-0.7071067811865475+0.7071067811865475j)

>>> np.isclose(np.exp(1j*ϑ), δj/abs(δj))
True # confirmed both methods yield the same result
```

```
-- Showing e^-iϑ = abs(δj)/ δj
>>> np.exp(-1j*ϑ)
(-0.7071067811865475-0.7071067811865476j)

>>> abs(δj)/δj
(-0.7071067811865476-0.7071067811865476j)

>>> np.isclose(np.exp(-1j*ϑ), abs(δj)/δj)
True # confirmed both methods yield the same result
```

With reluctance, my guess is -i there is a typo. Above is what I've got with python which indicates -i there is not really required. Could you confirm ?

Comment: It would be easier to follow your question if you showed the actual array values, rather than the `allclose` tests.

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever actually compute e to the power of anything.

Comment: And you forgot the `i` in `cos(x)+i*sin(x)`.

Comment: @user2357112, actually it should be `1j` in python

Comment: `np.cos(np.angle(δj)) + np.sin(np.angle(δj))` is not what your title or equation shows.  The answer is correct; you are wrong.

Comment: Vj is given by np.angle(δj). These are the panel angles. Not sure what you were saying but this is in the middle of the first equation.

Comment: The `sin` part of that calculation is supposed to complex; your python expression does not produce that.  Look at the result again: `array([ 1.11022302e-16, -1.41421356e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  1.41421356e+00])`

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that, still there is a mismatch between signs. values are now correct

Comment: It's been said, but again, you aren't computing e^i anything. Unsure what your equation is from, but it's likely you're misapplying the definitions. `e_iVj` is conceptually the normal vector of your edges--you're taking the vector along the edge, normalizing it to get the unit vector with the angle of that edge, and then multiplying it by -i (i.e. 90 degrees clockwise). In contrast, `cos(x) + i sin(x)` where `x = np.angle(z)` will give you the unit vector of the angle of that edge.

If you multiply your `cos(x) + i sin(x)` by -i, you'll get the results of `e_iVj`.

Comment: Hi @Kaia , what you say is correct except " you aren't computing e^i anything. ", May you please read the assert statements and try to see what I've done above ? You will see e_iVj is actually been calculated by taking δj/abs(δj). This is correct and I have already validated that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calculating the angle from `np.angle(δj)`, find the angle from either

- `np.angle(-1j * δj)`, or
- `np.angle(e_iVj)`

and then pass this angle to `np.cos(...) + 1j * np.sin(...)`.

That's the angle your formula uses in its RHS, not simply `δj`.

(I come from a [linked math.stackexchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4644654/complex-number-rotation-and-negation) and an updated answer is given there.)

Comment: hi @peterwhy, Thanks for having a look at this question. I've edited my question and tagged you for the specific section. Could you please let me know if that -i is actually should be there ?

Comment: @XYZ I can't judge what you want to do, and so whether there should be the -i. Do you actually want to find the `ϑ`, the angle of `δj`? Or do you still want to find `ν`, the angle of `-1j * δj`?

Answer (score 2):

You're not computing e^(i*theta) or cos(theta)+i*sin(theta). Your expressions don't make sense.

For an angle `theta`, this is how you would compute e^(i*theta):

```
np.exp(1j*theta)
```

and this is how you would compute cos(theta)+i*sin(theta):

```
np.cos(theta) + 1j*np.sin(theta)
```

Comment: Sorry this is incorrect. Above result I showed are valid for sure and fundamental property of complex numbers.

Comment: >>> np.angle(δj, deg=True) results in array([ 135., -135.,  -45.,   45.])

Comment: Thanks for having a look at the question though.